# Converting Compound Geometry class to Geopandas dataframe

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to convert geometries created with *section-properties* to geopandas dataframes for further processing. But I struggle to resolve the structure accordingly.

This is a modification of the  [example 07](https://sectionproperties.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sphinx_gallery_examples/00-basic/07_composite.html) from the docs. Note I had to replace `from shapely`  with `from shapely.geometry`  at several locations.

```
# sphinx_gallery_thumbnail_number = 2

import sectionproperties.pre.library.primitive_sections as sections
import sectionproperties.pre.library.steel_sections as steel_sections
from sectionproperties.pre.geometry import CompoundGeometry
from sectionproperties.pre.pre import Material
from sectionproperties.analysis.section import Section

# %%
# Create material properties
steel = Material(
    name="Steel",
    elastic_modulus=200e3,
    poissons_ratio=0.3,
    yield_strength=500,
    density=8.05e-6,
    color="grey",
)
timber = Material(
    name="Timber",
    elastic_modulus=8e3,
    poissons_ratio=0.35,
    yield_strength=20,
    density=0.78e-6,
    color="burlywood",
)

# %%
# Create 310UB40.4
ub = steel_sections.i_section(
    d=304, b=165, t_f=10.2, t_w=6.1, r=11.4, n_r=8, material=steel
)

# %%
# Create timber panel on top of the UB
panel = sections.rectangular_section(d=50, b=600, material=timber)
panel = panel.align_center(ub).align_to(ub, on="top")
# Create intermediate nodes in panel to match nodes in ub
panel = (panel - ub) | panel

# %%
# Merge the two sections into one geometry object
section_geometry = CompoundGeometry([ub, panel])

# convert to geopandas dataframe
import geopandas
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(section_geometry)
```

The result is this Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3936\1875453072.py in <module>
      1 import geopandas
----> 2 gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(section_geometry)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in __init__(self, data, geometry, crs, *args, **kwargs)
    133     def __init__(self, data=None, *args, geometry=None, crs=None, **kwargs):
    134         with compat.ignore_shapely2_warnings():
--> 135             super().__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
    136 
    137         # set_geometry ensures the geometry data have the proper dtype,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    754         else:
    755             if index is None or columns is None:
--> 756                 raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
    757 
    758             # Argument 1 to "ensure_index" has incompatible type "Collection[Any]";

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the last line to

```
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[section_geometry.geom])
```

output:

```
                                            geometry
0  MULTIPOLYGON (((0.000 0.000, 165.000 0.000, 16...
```